# Playing Youtube Video in iframe in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiwebview

Hello I'm parsing html string into web view and here is how I check for youtube videos and add them to iframe:

```
- (NSString *)extendYouTubeSupportInHtml:(NSString *)html {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static NSRegularExpression *youtubeEmbedRegex;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        youtubeEmbedRegex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"<object.*src.*/v/(.*?)['|\"].*object\\s*>" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
    });
    NSArray *matchs;
    if (html != nil) {

        matchs = [youtubeEmbedRegex matchesInString:html options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, html.length)];

    }else{
        matchs = nil;
    }

    NSInteger rangeOffset = 0;
    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matchs) {    
        NSRange objectRange = NSMakeRange([match rangeAtIndex:0].location + rangeOffset, [match rangeAtIndex:0].length);
        NSRange idRange = NSMakeRange([match rangeAtIndex:1].location + rangeOffset, [match rangeAtIndex:1].length);
        NSString* youtubrId = [html substringWithRange:idRange];

        // Add uniq id to img tag
        NSString* iframe = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<iframe src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", youtubrId];
        html = [html stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:objectRange withString:iframe];

        rangeOffset += iframe.length - objectRange.length;
    }

    return html;
}
```

And here is how I'm displaying the web view:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame dict:(NSDictionary *)dict {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.webView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)] autorelease];
        self.webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.webView.opaque = NO;
        self.webView.delegate = self;
        self.webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        self.webView.scalesPageToFit = NO;
        self.webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
        self.webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;

        [self removeBackgroundFromWebView:self.webView];      
        [self addSubview:self.webView];
        self.dictionary = dict;

    }
    return self;
}
```

My issue is that when I start playing video - memory usage is going up to 30MB, video starts to stutter, audio/video doesn't match, and when i close it - the memory usage is still the same.

I have a couple of leaks in AudioToolbox, also.
I'm using iOS 6 SDK, and iOS 6.
iOS 6 sdk broke the code - now it's not displaying anything in iOS 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my way of play a youtube video inside a app.

I am using iFrame to load youtube video inside my app.

follow this steps and you will too.

create a uiwebview and connect it to your .h file. Mine is _webView.

Add this method to your .m file.

```
-(void)embedYouTube{

    NSString *embedHTML = @"<iframe width=\"300\" height=\"250\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/rOPI5LDo7mg\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";

    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML];

    [_webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:_webView];

}
```

I am using the embedded code in youtube video. (I hope you know what it is)

call this method inside your viewdidload

```
[self embedYouTube];
```

Run the app and you will see the video in your view. This way is perfectly working for me and i think this will help for your too.

Comment: I have used same thing in my old app and it worked fine.But now video is not loading.Can you see your app and tell me if it is fine there?